# Dynamic equal-interval raster styling for LiDAR data

Tags: qgis, raster, style, lidar

I am looking for a way to create a colour map for raster (LiDAR) data in QGIS at equal-intervals (0.5 m, 1 m, 2m) which uses the same colour ramp whilst dynamically adjusting to the minimum and maximum of the raster data.

I have explored the different render types and saved and re-used styles. However, every time that I do this the minimum and maximum are applied from the previous raster used.

Essentially what I am after is a way to create and save a re-usable raster style in QGIS that will adjust to the maximum and minimum of LiDAR data. This will allow me to apply this style to any LiDAR data and visualise change in a consistent way.